# ajax img tag setup issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am try to send image with src tag in ajax . But facing chlange with setup img  Attribute in ajax .
Here is my script .
Please help me to set this line of script in src tag.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#image-data').html("{{asset('/images/product/medioum/')}}"+arr[2]);
    </script>
```

I am trying to achive this line of code but faciing chalange .Please help me to correct this.
Thanks

```
$('#image-data').html('<img src="{{asset('/images/product/medioum/')}}"+arr[2]>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved .
Here is Image Tag

```
 <img src="{{asset('images/product/medioum/'.$landing->image)}}" id="image-data">
```

And Here is solution. We can change Attributes of Any Image.

```
$('#image-data').attr("src","{{asset('/images/product/medioum/')}}/"+arr[2]);
```